# Gitlab-CI not triggering builds on commit

Tags: build, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Build not triggered since upgrade & migration

Hi, I upgraded to 8.8.3 the dockerized CE installation we have, and then migrated it to a new VM. The process was : docker-compose stop , rsync the docker volumes, docker-compose up -d on new server.

Since that time, when I do push commits, the CI are no more launched (gitlab-ci module), but I can run them manually from the pipelines tab.

When I do a push, I receive a hook error :

```
[tutu] git push origin  master                                                                                                                                                                                        9:26:07  ☁  master ☂ ✭ 
Décompte des objets: 6, fait.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compression des objets: 100% (5/5), fait.
Écriture des objets: 100% (6/6), 528 bytes | 0 bytes/s, fait.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: hooks/post-receive:27: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER,  expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
remote: exec git push --quiet github &
remote:                             ^
To ssh://git@git.XXXX:2222/MorningChecks/tutu.git
```

I don't know if this is linked. I don't know if I miss something from new feature usage or something, if this is the case, please apologize. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found.... One colleague of me added a commented line in the global hooks of project, don't know precisely why. The hook was failing and this is this precise hook that launches the builds.

So this has nothing to do with migration, upgrade, PEBKAC !

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Where exactly do you define global hooks, I googled but I could not find anything

Comment: Here : /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks

Answer (score 1):

The same behaviour, can also happen when using `needs` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`. If you are using two times the same jobs in your `needs`, GitLab Runner will fail silently to trigger the CI.

Example:

```
nightly:bin:
  stage: deploy
  needs: [ "buildA", "buildA" ]
  script:
    - echo "do stuff"
```

That's something!